# Vector3.MoveTowards not working with collisions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make smooth plane movement that follows the cursor.

This is the code that does so:

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 0;
        Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
        mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle + rotationOffset));

        Vector3 targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        targetPos.z = 0;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == targetPos)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
    }
```

This works well by its self but I have run into an issue where it doesn't detect collision. Ive never used `Vector3.MoveTowards` with movement before but I'm guessing that's the problem. If anyone had any suggestions it would be very appreciated.

Comment: What exact collision are you detecting? Are you relying on '(transform.position == targetPos)' to check if they are colliding?

Comment: @Armin The collisions im detecting are with other box coliders and the ```(transform.position == targetPos)``` is destroying the obj when it touches the cursor, the targetPos being the mouse position.

Comment: Was collision ever working for you? Does one of the objects in this collision have a `RigidBody2D`?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

- At least one of your objects needs to have a `Rigidbody2D` component
- both need to have a 2D collider.
- both need to be non-triggers

But that's not all: As soon as you use physics you do not want to move your objects via `Transform` in `Update` since this overules the physics and thereby breaks collision detection.

rather use e.g. [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) and [`Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html) within [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate.html)

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(! rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    var mousePosScreen = Input.mousePosition;
    var objectPosScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(rigidbody.position);

    var delta = mousePosScreen - objectPosScreen;
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(delta.y, delta.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var targetRotation = angle + rotationOffset;

    var mousePosWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosScreen);
    var targetPosWorld = Vector2.MoveTowards(rigidbody.position, mousePosWorld, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    rigidbody.MoveRotation(targetRotation);
    rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);

    if (rigidbody.position == targetPosWorld)
    {
        Die();
    }
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("hit");
}
```

Comment: Ah I completely forgot to consider the update method, good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Relating to Armin's comment, `transform.position==targetPos` will virtually never return true. That is just because of the large amount of precision in floats and [inherent problems with floating point comparison](https://www.twistedape.me.uk/2016/02/02/comparing-floating-point-numbers/).

A simple solution would be to check if the distance is within some delta. I recommend using square magnitude of distance for performance reasons. Example:

```
const float squareCollisionDistance = 4f;//actual collision distance will be 2
var offsetVector = targetPos-transform.position;
var squareDistance = offsetVector.sqrMagnitude;
if (squareDistance < squareCollisionDistance)
    {
        Die();
    }
```

Something else to look into is RigidBodies I think they have a collision event that you can listen to. Collision detection can be really tricky business and it is worthwhile to use Unity's built in features when you can.

Comment: If you look at the comment I made under his answer you can see I was being dum but edited the question. please refer to that

Comment: That's not true ... [`Vector3 ==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) uses an approximate precision of `0.00001` and therefore already offers a solution for floating point precision `MoveTowards` assures that at some point you will reach that position precise enough